# How do I refactor a switch-case using polymorphism?

Tags: c#, reflection, polymorphism

From the console I get commands in the format [command][position][value] e.g. multiply 2 3
and I am supposed to manipulate an array of integers according to the command.
For example if i have `int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 2, 0 };` after executing the "multiply 2 3" command the array should look like `{ 0, 8, 0 }`

The way I'm doing it now is by giving the info to a method that performs that manipulation.

```
static void PerformAction(int[] arr, string action, int position, int value)
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case "multiply":
                array[position] *= value;
                break;
            case "add":
                array[pos] += value;
                break;
            case "subtract":
                array[pos] -= value;
                break;
        }
    }
```

My question is - How do I apply polymorphism and/or reflection so I can just say:

```
ExecuteCommand(int[] arr, string action, int position, int value)
```

And maybe have a class for each command, so that every command knows how to be executed.

Comment: You could use the command pattern. A interface with one public method called execute with parameters ( int[] arr, position, value). Then each action implements the the interface.

Comment: Introduce an Operator with an `apply` method that only operates on `value`. You can then `array[position] = operatorMap.get( action ).apply( value );`

Answer (score 0):

A simple calculator using reflection would look something like this

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace StackOverFlow35166571
{
    public class ReflectionCalculator
    {
        public int Calculate(string action, int a, int b)
        {
            var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod(action, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var result = (int)methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] { a, b });
            return result;
        }

        private int Multiply(int a, int b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    }
}
```

A call would look like

```
var calc = new ReflectionCalculator();
var result = calc.Calculate("Multiply", 10, 3); // 30
```

A call using your inputs would look like

```
var calc = new ReflectionCalculator();
array[position] = calc.Calculate(action, array[position], value);
```